# im trying to put a function in .js file and call it in the html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1">


var slideimages=new Array()
function slideshowimages()
{
    for (i=0;i<slideshowimages.arguments.length;i++)
    {
        slideimages[i]=new Image()
        slideimages[i].src=slideshowimages.arguments[i]
    }
}

</script>

<script>
<!--

//configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links
slideshowimages("football.png","basketball.png","golf.png","mma.jpg","tennis.png","boxing.png")


//configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds
var slideshowspeed=4000

var whichlink=0
var whichimage=0
function slideit()
{
    if (!document.images)
    return
    document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
    whichlink=whichimage
    if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
    whichimage++
    else
    whichimage=0
    setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
}
slideit()

//-->
</script>
```

I would like to be able to have this JavaScript in its own file and not in the HTML. I've tried to do it but I'm not sure how to get it to work correctly. it works fine in the HTML file but not when I try call it. I'm not sure how to correctly call it.

Comment: How do you include the external js file?

Comment: There shouldn't be any `<script>` tags in your .js file

Comment: show your complete code.. try including .js file in head section of your HTML page

Comment: remove the `<script>` tags and put it in a file. load the file in html with `<script src="yourjavascriptfile"></script>`

Comment: JavaScript 1.1? The one released in what, 1996? On the plus side, you can [get the book for $0.01US](http://www.amazon.com/Teach-Yourself-Javascript-Week-Sams/dp/1575211955).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file with yourfilename.js and add your js methods in it. (Without script tag)

Link that file in your html's head like

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/your-path/youfilename.js" />
```

The rest will be same and your methods should work.

Comment: iv tried that but it diddnt work. maybe its my javascript do i need to change  if (!document.images)
    return
    document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src

Comment: if (!document.images)
    return
    document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
 change that to the name of the html file ?

Comment: its not necessary. document is used for every html file regardless of name. But you have error in the syntax of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

To use a JavaScript framework library in your web pages, just include the library in a  tag:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
```

You can also download it and have it locally and then change the source. ex.

```
          <script src="../js/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
          </script>
```